# Spring Security. ошибка 401 в браузере но не в postman

Tags: javascript, spring, безопасность, backend, jwt

Есть две страницы. Первая - login, вторая - chat. Если пользователь введет правильно свои данные в login, то сервер отправит ему jwt токен. Далее по кнопке пользователь должен перейти на страницу chat которая требует чтобы пользователь был авторизирован.
Отправляя запрос через postman с токеном у меня все хорошо. Показывается страница chat
Когда я делаю то же самое в браузере то при переходе на страницу chat выдается ошибка 401 :(
я не понимаю в чем ошибка, правда.
**вот часть конфигурации:**

```
auth.requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/login", "/signup", "/index.html", "/signup.html", "/css/signup.css", "/js/signup.js", "/login.html", "/css/login.css", "/js/login.js", "/js/chat.js", "/css/chat.css").permitAll(); //сделано
                    auth.requestMatchers("/chat.html", "/chat").authenticated();
```

**вот login.js**

```
document
  .getElementById("usernameForm")
  .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var username = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/auth/login", true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    var data = JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password });
    xhr.send(data);

    xhr.onload = function () {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        if (response.user == null) {
          displayError();
        } else {
          let jwt = response.jwt;
          localStorage.setItem("token", jwt);
          goToChat(jwt);
        }
      } else {
        console.log("Ошибка");
      }
    };
  });

function goToChat(jwt) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:8080/chat", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + jwt);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status == 200) {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/chat";
    } else {
      console.error("Error", xhr.status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Когда у вас открывается страница чата, после логина, у вас не передаются заголовки!  window.location.href = "http://localhost:8080/chat"; 
Браузер по умолчанию не вставляет заголовки, а тем более из localStorage. 
Если вы хотите завкрыть chat.html, то вам, скорее всего, нужно хранить токен в cookie и на сервере проверять их.

Comment: сейчас у меня jwt токен храниться в куки вот так document.cookie = "token=" + jwt; и xhr.setRequestHeader("Cookie", document.cookie); токен передается верный. как мне этот куки с токеном возможно обработать или что мне с ним делать дальше, чтобы пользователя все-таки пустило на страницу chat?

Comment: проблема была реально в хранении токенов. сейчас работает все через куки. спасибо, что подсказали

Answer (score 0):

Мне надо было работать с Куки. В заголовке токены хранятся лишь на 1 запрос. Потом они про упали. Поэтому их надо где-то хранить. Например, в Куки. Конечно, я еще поменяла CORS. Но основное, что надо было сделать - это добавить фильтр в конфигурацию, который бы считывал токен из куки и обрабатывал его

Comment: похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите

Comment: нет. это ответ)